# Find child element whose attribute has highest value within its container and then sort containers by the highest numbers

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I've have this (oversimplified for the purpose of this question) that i'm having trouble with. I want to be able to get the highest value of the distance-span (per regioncontainer) first and then sort the containing regioncontainers based on the obtained values.

```
<div id="onlineList">

  <div id="Zeeland" class="regioncontainer">
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="137"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="56"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="12"></span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="limburg" class="regioncontainer">
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="56"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="66"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="22"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="79"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="utrecht" class="regioncontainer">
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="12"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="55"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="76"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="11"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i've tried so far is which does the sorting ok but i'm a bit clueless on how to proceed. The onlineList-div is hardcoded in html and i want to detach and reattache the sorted divs to it.:

```
$('.regioncontainer').each(function(index, value) {
  var highestbyregion = $(this).children('div').children('.distance').map(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).attr('data-distance'), 10);
  }).get();

  var lowest = Math.min.apply(Math, highestbyregion);
  regiontemparr.push($(this), lowest);
});
```

Got it working with help from Aron.

```
    $('.regioncontainer).each(function(index, value) {
     var distance = 0;
     $(this).find('.distance').each(function() {
     if (distance < $(this).data('distance')) {
     distance = $(this).data('distance');
     }
     });

     $(this).attr('data-maxdistance', distance);
     });


    $('.regioncontainer').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).attr('data-maxdistance') - $(b).attr('data-      maxdistance');
    }).appendTo('#onlineList');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do soemthing like

```js
//find and cache the highest distance
$('.regioncontainer').each(function(index, value) {
  var distance = 0;
  $(this).find('.distance').each(function() {
    if (distance < $(this).data('distance')) {
      distance = $(this).data('distance');
    }
  });
  $(this).data('max-distance', distance);
});

//sort the elements
$('.regioncontainer').sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data('max-distance') - $(b).data('max-distance')
}).appendTo('#onlineList');
```

```css
.regioncontainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="onlineList">

  <div id="Zeeland" class="regioncontainer">
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="137">137</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="56">56</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="12">12</span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="limburg" class="regioncontainer">
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="56">56</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="66">66</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="22">22</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="79">79</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="utrecht" class="regioncontainer">
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="12">12</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="55">55</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="76">76</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="distance" data-distance="11">11</span>
    </div>              
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want but when i bring it into thge real environment the results aren't what i'd expect. This function at the start of your fidle? should be there to? $('.distance').text(function() {
  return $(this).data('distance')
});

Comment: I notice a funny thing at your fiddle just now. It doesn seam to matter if i put - or + at return $(a).data('max-distance') + $(b).data('max-distance'). Since i cannot seam to get it right in my own environment i wonder if iḿ overseeing some?

Comment: I had to change  $(this).data('distance', distance); to  $(this).attr('data-maxdistance', distance); cause it assumes the attr allready exists. :-)